# Android Ant and TeamCity

Tags: android, ant, teamcity, build.xml

Is it possible to get the android:versionCode & android:versionName from the AndroidManifest.xml file and use them in my Ant build.xml file? I would like to incorporate these values in my APK when built at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could use the XMLProperties task to achieve this.

```
<xmlproperty file="AndroidManifest.xml"/>
```

Should give you:

```
manifest(android:versionCode)="1"
manifest(android:versionName)="1.0"
```

According to the [definition in the Ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/xmlproperty.html) though I haven't tried/tested it.